# How to delete all custom sorting lists in vba?

Tags: excel, vba, list, sorting

I want to delete all (= a variable number of) custom sorting lists in vba excel, but I can't find the right syntax anywhere.

I know of two options:

1 write a command that automattically deletes all custom sortlists, this was my attempt at it:

```
Application.DeleteCustomList ()
```

2.a Write a command that returns the number of custom sortlists = b

2.b And then remove the custom sortlists manually with:

2.b.1:

```
for del = 0 to b
    Application.DeleteCustomList (del)
next del
```

2.b.2:

```
for del = 1 to b
    Application.DeleteCustomList (del)
next del
```

2.c

```
For delete_lists = 100 To 0 Step -1
    On Error Resume Next 'delete_list
    Application.DeleteCustomList (delete_lists)
Next delete_lists
```

Does anybody know a(ny) functioning way to achieve the goal?

Kind regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that Excel doesn't want you to delete the basic, existing custom lists. There are 4 of them on my Excel - but that may differ from one version to the next.

(Days of the week, months, etc... if you go to "File", "Options", "Advanced options", then at the bottom "Edit customs lists")

I think you safest bet is to resume next upon error:

```
Sub test()
On Error Resume Next
Dim i As Long
For i = 1 To Application.CustomListCount
   Application.DeleteCustomList (i)
Next i

On error GoTo 0
    End Sub
```

Or go to errHandler if you have some error handling procedure - because otherwise it may resume next for your whole script which may not be what you want.

Comment: Thank you very much, I forgot about the `Application.CustomListCount` option. That should do it!